Do the eigenvalues appear in pairs of opposite sign in this block matrix?

Let $( A \in \mathbb{M}_{m \times n} )$ have singular values $( \sigma_1 \geq \sigma_2 \geq \cdots \geq 0 )$. Show that the block matrix
\begin{pmatrix} 
\mathbf{0} & A \\\ A^* & \mathbf{0}
\end{pmatrix}
has eigenvalues $( \pm \sigma_1, \pm \sigma_2, \ldots )$, along with $( |m - n| )$ extra zero eigenvalues.

We know that its eigenvalues are real (because it is hermitian). Besides, the eigenvalues will be such that $| \lambda_i | = \sigma_i $. However, I was not able to prove that they will necessarily appear as pairs of opposite signs (if the exercise meant that). Is there something I am missing in the proof or I misinterpreted the problem's statement?

You interpret the exercise correctly, the eigenvalues come in pairs $+\sigma_i, -\sigma_i$.
Hint: it is not hard to construct the eigenvectors of this matrix from the singular vectors of $A$. Or you can unitarily transform the matrix into a block-diagonal one with $\begin{bmatrix}0 & \sigma_i \\ \sigma_i & 0\end{bmatrix}$ on the diagonal.

Vladmir's answer is correct. To supplement it, here's an alternative hint. Using block-matrix multiplication, note that
$$
\pmatrix{0 & U \Sigma V^*\\
V^* \Sigma^* U & 0} = \pmatrix{U \\&V}\pmatrix{0&\Sigma\\\Sigma^* & 0 }\pmatrix{U\\&V}^*.
$$

I understand this decomposition, but I am struggling to understand how comes that the eigenvalues appears as pairs of opposite sign (and not probably just repeated twice). This decomposition is not even spectral because the elements are in the antidiagonal, how did you make such conclusion from this? Thanks in advance.
